# Converting PyCall PyObject Decimal to Julia Float

Tags: python, julia, raspberry-pi3

When using PyCall in Julia and MySQLdb of python, the result of my select query is in  PyObject,

> PyObject Decimal('10')

How to convert it to plain Float so that I can get only the 10 ?

I tried the python version, float(response) but that doesnt work since im in Julia.

Comment: did you ```  your_decimal|> float ``` ?

Comment: havent tried it until I get the answer by using Julia's Convert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified in https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6.2/manual/conversion-and-promotion/,
It can be done by:

> julia> convert(AbstractFloat,response)
>
> 10.0

In fact it can also parse Python Objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually call `float` via `PyCall`. `convert`ing to `Float64` or `BigFloat` should also work.

```
julia> d = pyimport("decimal");

julia> response = d[:Decimal]("10")
PyObject Decimal('10')

julia> py"float"(response)
10.0

julia> convert(Float64, response)
10.0
```

Comment: oh, I forgot the py"float" part . Anyways, maybe the convert is much ideal since it is a built-in Julia function.

I have, question, when you are using PyCall, does calling the python bindings make Julia slow? Im using Julia v1.0 in Raspberry Pi with PyQt using PyCall.

Comment: I would guess both does the conversion of `PyObject` within Python via `float` first. By the way, with either method be careful with the conversion since `Decimal` is arbitrary precision.

Comment: I don't think it makes your other Julia functions slower, if that's what you are asking. If you have a question or problem regarding performance, maybe you should ask in another one here or on Julia Discourse.

Comment: Yea, because Julia is compiled. Thank you for the answer sir :)